# On browser close beforeunload - how to find if user selected "Stay" or "Leave"

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, jquery-events

To keep things very simple - I have the following code

```
$(window).bind("beforeunload",function(event) {
    return '';
})
```

At least on Chrome,FireFox and IE9 - when a user closes the browser - he is presented with two options - "Stay on Page" or "Leave this Page" (The message varies from browser to browser)

Now how can I find out what option the user selected?
For sake of simplicity - lets say - I want to show an extra message based on which option the user selected.

Something like - just to give an idea:

```
if(option=="Stay on Page")
   alert("Thanks for continuing to stay");
if(option=="Leave this page")
   alert("Sorry you decided to go - please come back soon");
```

How do I capture - what the user selected.

Comment: Did you got to know how to detect which option user has selected? "Stay on Page" or "Leave this Page"? If so please share the code sample, I am looking for similar kind of behavior but no sample found till now.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, you are not allowed to do that, for security reasons. The only thing you can do is the below:

```
window.onbeforeunload = function(){
    return 'Your confirmation message';
}
```

Comment: Thanks Mark - my idea is not to show alert messages to the user - all I want to know is if he is really leaving or deciding to stay based on which I have to call a backend task...