# How to find if user selected “Stay” or “Leave” button after beforeunload alert?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to logout() user session when user leave website by closing web browser. I am using below code to display alert if user closes browser.

**Code:-**

```
$(window).bind('beforeunload', function () {
    return '';
});
```

Now I want to find whether use user have clicked "Leave this page" button or not. So that I can logout that user.

I found some threads on Stack overflow, but none are useful on this scenario.

[On browser close beforeunload - how to find if user selected "Stay" or "Leave"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11271919/on-browser-close-beforeunload-how-to-find-if-user-selected-stay-or-leave?rq=1)

[jquery beforeunload when closing (not leaving) the page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18783535/jquery-beforeunload-when-closing-not-leaving-the-page)

[javascript before leaving the page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7080269/javascript-before-leaving-the-page)

Answer (score 1):

I found solution.

**Code:-**

```
$(window).bind('beforeunload', function () {
    return '';
});

$(window).bind('unload', function () {
    logout();
});
```

Hope it will be useful to someone.